# Sort function using recursive logic

Tags: ruby, sorting, recursion

I am trying to write the `Array.sort` method in my own way using recursive logic. My code is as follows:

```
def sorting_array(unsorted,sorted)
  temp=unsorted
  if unsorted.length==0
    return sorted
  elsif unsorted.length==1
    return sorted.push(unsorted[0])
  else    
  end
  if unsorted[0]<=unsorted[1] # check the first position and add
    sorted.push(unsorted.shift)
    sorting_array(unsorted,sorted)
  else # add the 0th element to the end to handle later
    unsorted.push(unsorted.shift)
    sorting_array(unsorted,sorted)
  end
end

array=["pat","aog","cig","Zig","forse","erdvark", "aag"]
p sorting_array(array,[])
```

I appreciate any insight or input on where I am messing this up.

Comment: So what problems are you having?  What is your output?  What have you tried?  What do you notice?   You never use the variable `temp` so why have it?

Comment: So what I see is you are pushing elements into the sorted array.  Elements that make to the sorted array won't necessarily be sorted in the sorted array, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry.... temp was leftover from testing and I failed to remove it. When I use .sort it returns "["Zig", "aag", "aog", "cig", "erdvark", "forse", "pat"]" but when I use my method it returns
["aog", "Zig", "aag", "cig", "erdvark", "forse", "pat"]... which obviously is not accurate.

Comment: Vee... maybe I am wrong, but what I am seeing is that if the array[0] is the smallest (or equal) in unsorted, it will get pushed into the sorted array.  If it is not the smallest, it will get pushed to the end of unsorted... where eventually the smallest item will be the last item left in unsorted.  Once that gets pushed, my thought is that sorted should be ordered. - Obviously that is not how it is working, but I am not seeing my flaw.

Comment: Why don't you look up some well known recursive sorting algorithm, like quicksort or merge sort, and implement it in ruby? A recursive algorithm will break the problem into smaller parts and solve those parts, then assemble the solutions to the smaller problems into a solution for the larger problem. Your algorithm isn't really doing this.

Comment: actually, I think this question should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if unsorted[0]<=unsorted[1] #idea is to check the first position and add
    sorted.push(unsorted.shift)
    sorting_array(unsorted,sorted)
```

The problem comes here: you push `unsorted[0]` into `sorted` when `unsorted[0] <= unsorted[1]`, no matter if `unsorted[0]` is the smallest in `unsorted`.

Try this: `unsorted = [100, 101, 1, 2]`.

Comment: OK, so that makes sense and now I have set my temp variable to 'zzzzzzzzz' and added an `  unsorted.each do |x|
    if x<=temp
      temp=x
    end
    p temp
  end` that looks like it handles it and seems to handle it, but I really am thinking that I made this far too long of a piece of code for what it should be... like I am missing out on what the recursion should look like.  any ideas? and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your underlying algorithm is broken and will not produce a sorted array in all cases. Here's a simple counter example. These are arrays of strings of numbers. I'm just lazy and omitted the single/double quotes in the array definitions:

```
[2, 5, 0 ,4]
"2" <= "5" => true
[2] , [5, 0, 4]
"5" <= "0" => false
[2] , [0, 4, 5]
"0" <= "4" => true
[2, 0] , [4, 5]
"4" <= "5" => true
[2, 0, 4] , [5] <=== At this point your "sorted" array is clearly not sorted
```

Part of the problem is your code here:

```
if unsorted[0]<=unsorted[1]
  sorted.push(unsorted.shift)
  sorting_array(unsorted,sorted)
```

The `if` statement doesn't provide the kind of guarantee you need to push something into your sorted array.